# Sending Email in PHP from a button

Tags: php, email

Let me start by saying I do not have a lot of programming knowledge.  I use a program called PHPRunner to generate most of the php that I do. It is mainly for small office stuff nothing fancy.

My question is:
I have a table that has 6 fields one of them called email.  When I go into a record I wanted to put a button called "send notification" that would email the record details to the email address associated with that record.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I know it is probably out here on the web, possibly searching the wrong way.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the button will not send the email. It will send a request to a PHP page on the server that will process and send an email for you. This means the button will be a link, and the page will change. If you would like the button to send an email without leaving or refreshing the page you need to look at using javascript/jQuery. But I wouldn't advise this if you are new to programming as it may confuse you :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function in php. Example from the provided link:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending email using PHP, use `mail()` function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

**Example:**

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$from    = 'webmaster@example.com';
$headers = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$from . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```